# How can I detect if app was launched by user clicking notification on macOS now that launchUserNotificationUserInfoKey has been deprecated?

Tags: swift, macos, appkit

I used to use [NSUserNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsusernotification)’s [launchUserNotificationUserInfoKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428715-launchusernotificationuserinfoke) to detect if app was launched by user clicking notification on macOS.

```swift
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
  var notificationCenterLaunch = false
  func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (allowed, error) in
      // Check if notifications are allowed
      if allowed {
        // Check if app was launched by clicking on notification
        if notification.userInfo?[NSApplication.launchUserNotificationUserInfoKey] != nil {
          self.notificationCenterLaunch = true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Given `NSUserNotification` has been deprecated, I refactored codebase to use `UNUserNotification`, but now, `launchUserNotificationUserInfoKey` is no longer present in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`’s notification object.

How can I detect if app was launched by user clicking notification on macOS?

Comment: Please read https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/handling_notifications_and_notification-related_actions

Comment: Thanks for helping out @vadian. Does this apply to macOS?

Comment: I had already read this article… but, unfortunately, [launchUserNotificationUserInfoKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate/nsapplicationdidfinishlaunching_user_info_keys) is never fired even when app is launched by user clicking notification. I have spent at least 10 hours trying to solve this issue.

Comment: @vadian Would you happen to have any ideas that might help me solve this? 

Comment: Yes, it does. `launchUserNotificationUserInfoKey` is not being used in the UserNotification framework. Instead the delegate method is called.

Comment: So how can I know if app was launched by user clicking notification then?

Comment: My app is a wrapper that runs a command line when it launches. I am trying to have it not run same command when launched using notification given, in that use case, I want to run different command that opens log file instead.

Comment: From the article: ***When the user selects an action, the system launches your app in the background and calls the delegate’s userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:) method.***

Comment: I have implemented that. Problem is, I believe it runs after applicationDidFinishLaunching… I need a way to run different commands based on the context.

Comment: If your app is not running when a notification is received then you are talking about **remote notifications**. In this case you have to register for remote notifications and implement `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:)`. In any case and as soon as possible – preferable in `awakeFromNib` –  ask for permission to receive notifications and set the `UNUserNotificationCenter` delegate on success. Doing this in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is too late.

Comment: @vadian Does `awakeFromNib` apply to agent apps (“Application is agent“ => “YES”)? The app runs using launch agent script every hour to initiate [Borg](https://www.borgbackup.org/) backups (see https://github.com/sunknudsen/borg-wrapper). Notifications are used to show when backups are initiated and when they complete (or fail). Clicking notification opens backup logs (see [this](https://github.com/sunknudsen/borg-wrapper/blob/master/Borg%20Wrapper/AppDelegate.swift#L154) line).

Comment: Please try it. If `awakeFromNib` is not called, at least `applicationWillFinishLaunching` will be called which occurs before `applicationDid...`, too.

Comment: @vadian Would you happen to know what is called before `userNotificationCenter`? I need a way to know when app is launched because of user clicking notification vs double-click on app or using launch agent script.

Comment: Once again, `UNUserNotificationCenter` works in a different way. There is no key passed in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. The framework calls `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)` (or `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:)`for a remote notification) and you have to specify the actions and categories you want to perform just after setting the `UNUserNotificationCenter` delegate.

Comment: Is the question "How can I detect if app was **not** launched by user clicking notification"?

Comment: Hey @Willeke, thanks for helping out. That would also work I believe. I need a way to know the context in which app was launched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this issue is caused by a bug in macOS Big Sur 11.6 rather than [launchUserNotificationUserInfoKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428715-launchusernotificationuserinfoke) been deprecated (which I likely assumed by mistake)?

Everything works as expected in macOS Big Sur 11.6.1 or macOS Monterey.