# How to have background agent app run function hourly on macOS?

Tags: swift, macos

I am developing an app and I would like to run function hourly on macOS (at 8:00, 9:00, 10:00, …).

I used to use `~/Library/LaunchAgents/…`, but notifications are [broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69660669/how-can-i-detect-if-app-was-launched-by-user-clicking-notification-on-macos-now) when app is not running in background.

Similar to Linux cron job… is that possible?

Comment: If your app will be in the foreground, using a `Timer` should be enough. If your app may be closed, you'll probably want to create a daemon.

Comment: Not sure what best approach is, but app could be left running in background if that doesn’t affect battery life…

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like it when you're logged in, use a Launch Agent. If you want it even when no one is logged in, use a Launch Daemon.

See [Creating Launch Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) in the Daemons and Services Programming Guide.

Ultimately, you'll create a plist file such as this one (from the docs) that specifies the interval you want (very much like cron):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.touchsomefile</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>touch</string>
        <string>/tmp/helloworld</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>45</integer>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>13</integer>
        <key>Day</key>
        <integer>7</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This will go in `/Library/LaunchDaemons`, `/Library/LaunchAgents` or `~/Library/LaunchDaemons`, depending on whether you want it tied to the whole system, all users, or just one user.

Note that Launch Daemons have no access to the windowing system, so it's hard for them to do things like launch programs. They also may be more limited than you'd expect to user data. (Running as root can give you less access than running as a user.)

See also `man launchctl` for loading and unloading them by hand, and monitoring them generally.

Comment: Thanks for helping out Rob! This is what I am [currently using](https://github.com/sunknudsen/borg-wrapper#scheduling-backups). Unfortunately, it appears this approach [no longer works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69660669/how-can-i-detect-if-app-was-launched-by-user-clicking-notification-on-macos-now) for my use case.

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you mean here by "no longer works." Does this not launch your app? It seems the question isn't about launching the app, but how to know why the app was launched. If you want to know you were launched by the LaunchAgent, pass a parameter (you can read it with `NSProcessInfo.arguments`.

Comment: If you want to wait for notifications, I'd just leave the app running all the time. As long as the app isn't memory hungry, just sitting doing nothing doesn't cost much, and this is how users are used to things working (so you show up in Activity Monitor). If it's big, I'd make a small XPC daemon that runs all the time and launches the UI only if needed.

Comment: Using this approach launches app… but once app has exited, clicking notification doesn’t work as expected. Instead of firing userNotificationCenter, app relaunches. Apparently userNotificationCenter is only fired when app is running. Really puzzled about this problem… hence why I am experimenting with different approach.

Comment: Interesting… so `~/Library/LaunchAgents/…` would not run separate instances right? So if app is already running, it would do nothing? If so, how does this approach affect battery life if app is essentially a wrapper that call a shell script once per hour? Thanks again for helping out!

Comment: Actually, I do not think this would work… given a single instance would run, the `~/Library/LaunchAgents/…` “cron” would not fire app, therefore would not fire logic.